# Suspend problem on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: suspend, power-management

I installed Ubuntu 16.04. When I run the terminal command `sudo pm-suspend` my computer suspends, and pressing any key brings it out of suspend.

But when I press the "Suspend" key on the keyboard or choose "Suspend" from the main menu, my computer suspends *but doesn't wake up* when I press any key on the keyboard.

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: If you suspend your computer by the keyboard or the menu, can you wake the computer by pressing the power button? Please let us know.

Comment: No I can't wake it. Wake up is possible only when i use terminal command